# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Y' for SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

The following code:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
System.out.println("Month " + month + " year " + year);
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM YYYY");
e.setMonthnYear(dt1.format(now.getTime()));
```

After deploying on server is showing following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Y'
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:768)
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:575)
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:500)
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:475)
    iland.employee.EmployeeAction.fetchAllAtted(EmployeeAction.java:169)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

On my local host I am using `JDK v1.8` and the above code is working perfectly, but on server it is not working.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to check java version on your server. If it is not Java 8 or less than Java 7 the `Y` will not work there.

Comment: I replaced YYYY with yyyy(lowercase) it started working, as mentioned below in answers must be issue with Java versions.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

try

```
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");
```

Comment: As OP is using Java 1.8 the capital `Y` is valid for Week Year. Refer to Java 8 [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev just a little doubt javadoc says- If week year 'Y' is specified and the calendar doesn't support any week years, the calendar year ('y') is used instead. So according to that Y should not have thrown IllegalArgumentException right?

Comment: @M.Sharma it depends on Java version, but even if it is Java 8 and Y does not throw an exception, it has a different meaning and will be interpreted incorrectly

Answer (score 38):

On your Local you might be using Java 8, so do check the version of Java on your Server. If it is less than Java JDK 7 the capital `Y` will not work.

Refer To Java 6 Oracle Docs for [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

**You have to write year in small `y` not in capitals `Y`.**

Like for 2 digit year:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yy");
```

And for 4 digit year:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
```

In case if you are using Java 7 or above:
You can use the capital `Y` which represents `Week Year`.

Refer to Java 7 Oracle Docs [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Can somebody explain for a non-native english speaker what a concept of "Week Year" means?

Comment: Maybe this link will help to know, how Week Year internally works in Java.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691582/how-does-java-week-year-really-work

Comment: Is according language? @MandarPandit. it is because in a Android project, only devices with pt-BR language has crached.

Answer (score 15):

## Android

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) differs from the implementation. The supported characters are defined in a string constant in `SimpleDateFormat` up to API level 23. From the [source code](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java#L211):

```
static final String PATTERN_CHARS = "GyMdkHmsSEDFwWahKzZLc";
```

Since 'Y' (Week Year) is not included, the pattern validation throws the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'
```

A quick fix, when week year behaviour isn't required, is to use the 'y', e.g.: `yyyy-MM-dd`.

'Y' as a pattern character is supported as of API level 24.

## Update

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) now lists the supported API levels for pattern characters.

Answer (score 7):

As per the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
If week year 'Y' is specified and the calendar doesn't support any week years,
the calendar year ('y') is used instead. The support of week years can be tested
with a call to getCalendar().isWeekDateSupported().
```

So the only problem is guess is your version of java < 1.7 because
JRE1.7 has added 'Y' pattern for Week year and in JRE1.6 there is no pattern for this.

Or simply stay on the safer side use `y` instead of `Y`.

One more thing always try to use locale to be on safer side

```
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy",java.util.Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 2):

i have taken this table from java docs.

```
Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
G   Era designator  Text    AD
y   Year    Year    1996; 96
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
w   Week in year    Number  27
W   Week in month   Number  2
D   Day in year Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
F   Day of week in month    Number  2
E   Day in week Text    Tuesday; Tue
```

In your case just replace"Y" to "y" 
 you can see [Docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I guess, because the downvoters think that it is irrelevant to the Question.  I agree with that proposition.

Answer (score 0):

From [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples 
y       Year                    Year            1996; 96
Y       Week year               Year            2009; 09
```

You are asking for `Week year` instead of `year` in your call to `SimpleDateFormat()`