# java date parse missbehaviour

Tags: java, date

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, YYYY, EEE", Locale.US);

System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
System.out.println(sdf.format(sdf.parse("Apr 27, 2018, Fri")));
```

Java does not parse the date as expected and outputs:

```
Apr 27, 2018, Fri
Jan 05, 2018, Fri // I can not understand why java parse the month of April as January
```

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated along with `Date`, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `YYYY`, which represents `Week year`, whereas you wanted `yyyy` which represents `year`, see all options [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, EEE", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 3):

As per [SimpleDateFormat Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
y    Year    
Y    Week year
```

So you want to use `yyyy` instead `YYYY`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, EEE", Locale.US);

System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
System.out.println(sdf.format(sdf.parse("Apr 27, 2018, Fri")));
```

will result int:

```
Apr 27, 2018, Fri
Apr 27, 2018, Fri
```

Do note that you probably want to set [`sdf.setLenient(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) when using SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the other answers, what you want is `yyyy` instead of `YYYY` .

Now to add further information about the resut you get :

Date String : `"Apr 27, 2018, Fri"`

Format : `"MMM dd, YYYY, EEE"`  (`YYYY` being week year)

Quoting from [How does Java “week year” really work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691582/how-does-java-week-year-really-work)

> On parsing, SimpleDateFormat expects a matching set of values: either
>   day, month, year or day of week, week in year, week-year. Since you
>   supplied a week-year but did not supply day of week and week in year,
>   those to values have been assumed as 1.

You don't have the *week in year* part (or your format would contain `w`), so it is assumed to be 1 .

You end up having **friday** of the **first week** of the year **2018**, which is :

```
Jan 05, 2018, Fri
```

(The day and the month from your date get discarded once the format hits the `YYYY` part, and are replaced by the result of the "year week" computing. )

Answer (score 0):

Y stands for week year

From Java doc

> A week year is in sync with a WEEK_OF_YEAR cycle. All weeks between
>   the first and last weeks (inclusive) have the same week year value.
>   Therefore, the first and last days of a week year may have different
>   calendar year values.
>
> For example, January 1, 1998 is a Thursday. If getFirstDayOfWeek() is
>   MONDAY and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() is 4 (ISO 8601 standard
>   compatible setting), then week 1 of 1998 starts on December 29, 1997,
>   and ends on January 4, 1998. The week year is 1998 for the last three
>   days of calendar year 1997. If, however, getFirstDayOfWeek() is
>   SUNDAY, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and ends on
>   January 10, 1998; the first three days of 1998 then are part of week
>   53 of 1997 and their week year is 1997.